# Non-empty stable locus in an irreducible component

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, quiver, geometric-invariant-theory

I have a vague question:

Let $X$ be an algebraic pre-scheme and $G$ be a linear reductive group. Consider the G.I.T quotient $X//G$. Is there any result (maybe in some special case) which tells us when the stable locus $X^{s}$ will be non-empty?

Any kind of reference, addressing the above question, will be useful.

I'm particularly interested in the case of bound quivers (King's stability conditions) as follows:

Let $\alpha$ be a dimension vector and $A$ be a finite-dimensional algebra over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$. We take an irreducible component $C$ of $mod_{A}(\alpha)$. Then, we have the action of $GL_{\alpha}$ on $C$ and we take a stability parameter (or weight) $\theta$ and construct the G.I.T quotient and hence we get the moduli space $\mathcal{M}(\alpha,\theta)$ and I would like to know if there are some conditions that allow us to say that $\mathcal{M}^{s}(\alpha,\theta)$ won't be empty.